# Add Outline/Stroke effect to UITextView ios <7

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, uitextview

I'm looking for the solution to add outline/stroke to the text inside a UITextView 
For UILabel, I can easily do this by override `- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect` 
I also found some solution but they didn't work for me: 
- For iOS 7, I found this can be solved by using `NSString` method: `drawInRect:rect withAttributes:` like this

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSMutableDictionary *stringAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    // Define the font and fill color
    [stringAttributes setObject: self.font forKey: NSFontAttributeName];
    [stringAttributes setObject: self.textColor forKey: NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
    // Supply a negative value for stroke width that is 2% of the font point size in thickness
    [stringAttributes setObject: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: -2.0] forKey: NSStrokeWidthAttributeName];
    [stringAttributes setObject: self.strokeColor forKey: NSStrokeColorAttributeName];

    // Draw the string
    [self.text drawInRect:rect withAttributes:stringAttributes];
}
```

- Some others tell just use UIWebview to use CSS [Adding outline/stroke to UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250148/adding-outline-stroke-to-uitextview)

Are there any solution that can be supported for iOS <7 ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I update the answer for someone also looking for this question. 
Subclass UITextView and override the drawRect function like this

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGSize size = [self.text sizeWithFont:self.font constrainedToSize:rect.size lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    CGRect textRect = CGRectMake((rect.size.width - size.width)/2,(rect.size.height - size.height)/2, size.width, size.height);

    //for debug
    NSLog(@"draw in rect: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(rect));
    NSLog(@"content Size : %@", NSStringFromCGSize(self.contentSize));
    NSLog(@"Text draw at :%@", NSStringFromCGRect(textRect));

    CGContextRef textContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(textContext);
    //set text draw mode and draw the stroke
    CGContextSetLineWidth(textContext, 2); // set the stroke with as you wish
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (textContext, kCGTextStroke);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(textContext, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);

    [self.text drawInRect:textRect withFont:self.font lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    CGContextRestoreGState(textContext);
}
```